# Sum or Percentage of a word in the results / column

Tags: visual-studio, report, expression

I have a report that in part is providing: Job Date, Job Target Date and Completion date.

I have a column at the end that works out whether or not the job was completed within the target time our outside of returning true or false.

As mentioned, I have created a column to work out whether a job is completed on time and I have tried googling many different solutions and trying them out.

The expression I've used to work out whether the job was completed on time is:
=IIF(Fields!CompletedDate.Value <= Fields!Target.Value, "True", "False")

Now I need an expression to work out the percentage that are within the target. So, let's say there are 80 jobs and 67 are completed in time. It would be 'True' (67) / 80 *100 = 83%.

The expression I've used to work out whether the job was completed on time is:
=IIF(Fields!CompletedDate.Value <= Fields!Target.Value, "True", "False")

Now I need an expression to work out the percentage that are within the target. So, let's say there are 80 jobs and 67 are completed in time. It would be 'True' (67) / 80 *100 = 83%.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out myself, again..

If anyone is interested I kept the same IF statement in the original cell. I then created 2 additional cells underneath one containing the text 'Percentage of jobs completed on target' and the other cell I added a new expression that included the original one above;

=SUM(IIF(Fields!CompletedDate.Value <= Fields!Target.Value, 1, 0)) / count(Fields!PropertyCode.Value)

All I had to keep in mind was that I am already showing the results as true and false so in my seconds expression I change the values to numbers so I can calculate. True is '1' so I know that it will not be calculating on 0 as it cannot divide by zero.
So, I did a sum on the number true represented as 1 divided by number of results. Rather than times this by 100 ( 5/19*100 = percentage), I simply left out the times and changed the format of that cell to percentage so it takes the value in the cell and returns the percentage.

Thanks,
Jordan